# Angular Deep nested Form Array How to create?

Tags: angular

I have tried deep nested form array. but i got some error. I dont know how to fix it. i am  new in angular framework.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pezmpp?file=src/form.component.ts). I have shared code link.